# No connection to Kafka from Faust client

Tags: networking, python, firewalld, opensuse, kafka

I am having a hard time connection to a machine running Kafka from a client running a Faust script.The script looks like this:

```
import faust
import logging
from asyncio import sleep


class Test(faust.Record):
    msg: str


app = faust.App('myapp', broker='kafka://10.0.0.20:9092')
topic = app.topic('test', value_type=Test)


@app.agent(topic)
async def hello(messages):
    async for message in messages:
        print(f'Received {message.msg}')


@app.timer(interval=5.0)
async def example_sender():
    await hello.send(
        value=Test(msg='Hello World!'),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.main()
```

When I run the script:

```
# faust -A myapp worker -l info
┌ƒaµS† v0.8.1─┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id          │ myapp                                           │
│ transport   │ [URL('kafka://10.0.0.20:9092')]                 │
│ store       │ memory:                                         │
│ web         │ http://hubbabubba:6066                   │
│ log         │ -stderr- (info)                                 │
│ pid         │ 260765                                          │
│ hostname    │ hubbabubba                               │
│ platform    │ CPython 3.8.10 (Linux x86_64)                   │
│ drivers     │                                                 │
│   transport │ aiokafka=0.7.2                                  │
│   web       │ aiohttp=3.8.1                                   │
│ datadir     │ /Git/faust-kafka/myapp-data    │
│ appdir      │ /Git/faust-kafka/myapp-data/v1 │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,018] [260765] [INFO] [^Worker]: Starting... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,021] [260765] [INFO] [^-App]: Starting... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,021] [260765] [INFO] [^--Monitor]: Starting... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,021] [260765] [INFO] [^--Producer]: Starting... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,022] [260765] [INFO] [^---ProducerBuffer]: Starting... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,024] [260765] [ERROR] Unable connect to "10.0.0.20:9092": [Errno 113] Connect call failed ('10.0.0.20', 9092) 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,025] [260765] [ERROR] [^Worker]: Error: KafkaConnectionError("Unable to bootstrap from [('10.0.0.20', 9092, <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>)]") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Git/faust-kafka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/worker.py", line 276, in execute_from_commandline
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self._starting_fut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Git/faust-kafka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 759, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/media/eric/DISK3/Git/faust-kafka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 766, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()...
  File "/Git/faust-kafka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 249, in bootstrap
    raise KafkaConnectionError(
kafka.errors.KafkaConnectionError: KafkaConnectionError: Unable to bootstrap from [('10.0.0.20', 9092, <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>)]
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,027] [260765] [INFO] [^Worker]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,027] [260765] [INFO] [^-App]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,027] [260765] [INFO] [^-App]: Flush producer buffer... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,028] [260765] [INFO] [^--TableManager]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,028] [260765] [INFO] [^---Fetcher]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,028] [260765] [INFO] [^---Conductor]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,028] [260765] [INFO] [^--AgentManager]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,029] [260765] [INFO] [^Agent: myapp.hello]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,029] [260765] [INFO] [^--ReplyConsumer]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,029] [260765] [INFO] [^--LeaderAssignor]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,029] [260765] [INFO] [^--Consumer]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,030] [260765] [INFO] [^--Web]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,030] [260765] [INFO] [^--CacheBackend]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,030] [260765] [INFO] [^--Producer]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,030] [260765] [INFO] [^---ProducerBuffer]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,031] [260765] [INFO] [^--Monitor]: Stopping... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,032] [260765] [INFO] [^Worker]: Gathering service tasks... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:57,032] [260765] [INFO] [^Worker]: Gathering all futures... 
[2022-01-28 13:09:58,033] [260765] [INFO] [^Worker]: Closing event loop
```

Kafka (v.2.8.1) is running on 10.0.0.20, port 9092. The Kafka configuration looks like this:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

The Kafka-broker starts without a hitch with:

```
$ sudo bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties
```

I get the topic going with:

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I then check with:

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
test
```

So I wonder where I messed up. BTW: The server is reachable from the client machine:

```
$ ping -c 5 10.0.0.20 -p 9092
PATTERN: 0x9092
PING 10.0.0.20 (10.0.0.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.468 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.790 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.918 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.20: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.453 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.20: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.827 ms

--- 10.0.0.20 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4095ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.453/0.691/0.918/0.192 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong to me, as it would imply that your remote client is going to attempt to connect to `localhost` once it's talked to the bootstrap server, not the remote address of your kafka instance:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

I would change that to the external (10.x.x.x) IP of your kafka instance, restart everything, and try again.

Comment: Set advertised.listeners to 10.0.0.20 and added port 9092 to allowed ports. Restarted everything. Works! Thanks.